# How to recognize removable singularity and how to remove it

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition

I don't understand the idea of a removable singularity yet. Can someone explain me how to recognize a removable singularity and how to remove it?

Example: $g(z)=f(z)/z$. Is $z=0$ then a removable singularity and if yes, how would I remove it?

Comment: I assume $f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$. It's removable if and only if $f$ has a zero in $0$. You remove it by extending $g$ to have the appropriate value in $0$ so that $g$ becomes continuous (and hence analytic) in $0$; the value would be $f'(0)$ here.

Comment: @DanielFischer How did you conclude that the value would be $f'(0)$?

Comment: For example Taylor expansion. $f(z) = f(0) + z\cdot f'(0) + \frac{z^2}{2}f''(0) + \dotsb$. With $f(0) = 0$, we get $\frac{f(z)}{z} = f'(0) + \frac{z}{2}f''(0) + \dotsb$, which is easily seen to be continuous if we set the value to $f'(0)$ for $z = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Great!

Answer (score 1):

If both $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic at $z_0$, they have Taylor expansions $$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(z-z_0)^k,\quad g(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k(z-z_0)^k$$ 
Let $m$ be the smallest index for which $a_k\ne 0$, and $n$ be the smallest index for which $b_k\ne 0$. Then 
$$
\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} =  z^{m-n}\frac{a_{m }+a_{m+1}(z-z_0)+\dots}{b_{n}+b_{n+1}(z-z_0)+\dots}
\tag{1}$$ 
where the fraction on the right is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z_0$   (because the denominator does not vanish), and takes on the nonzero value $a_m/b_n$ at $z_0$. The behavior of $f/g$ at $z_0$ is determined by $m-n$. If $m\ge n $, you have removable singularity, since the right-hand side of (1) is holomorphic. If $m<n $, you get a pole.